# The concurrency property of the diagonals (semidiagonals) of bicentric polygons.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polygons

After answering a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3592891) where the collinearity of the points $X,O,I$ was proven in an elementary way, I rather soon came to the conclusion that the intersection point $X$ of the diagonals is completely fixed by the positions ($O,I$) and the radii ($R,r$) of the circumscribed and inscribed circles (i.e. the product $\sin\alpha\sin\beta$ in the cited answer is a constant for given $R,r$). After some algebra I obtained the following simple formula:
$$
XI=\frac rR\sqrt{\frac{R^2+d^2-2r^2}2},
$$
where $d$ is the distance between the centers of the circumscribed and inscribed circles $OI$ (given $R$ and $r$, it is fixed by the [Poncelet porism](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PonceletsPorism.html)).

To my surprise I did not find any mention of the above formula in the online sources. But during the search I realized that the formula follows from a much more general statement cited in the above reference:

> *For an even-sided [bicentric] polygon, the diagonals are concurrent at the limiting point of the two circles, whereas for an odd-sided polygon, the lines connecting the vertices to the opposite points of tangency are concurrent at the limiting point.*

I am looking for a (possibly simple) proof of the above statement and/or reference to the original publication on this result.

Comment: I revisited this and found (through Geogebra experiments) that the statement is not true for odd-sided bicentric polygons.  In general the diagonals don't go through the limiting point and are not concurrent.  I've contacted Mathworld about this.

Comment: This would be very surprising.

Comment: For example, for the case $n=3$, the semi-diagonals intersect at the Gergonne point, which is different from (but quite close to) the limiting point.

Comment: This means that in a triangle the semi-diagonals are still concurrent, is not it? For which $n$ they cancel to be concurrent?

Comment: Yes, they are concurrent for $n=3$.  They are not concurrent for $n=5$.

Comment: The problems with finding a proof for odd $n$ were suspicious enough. Let me know the answer of Mathworld.

Comment: Will do. But it might take a while. Their system for handling this sort of thing seems quite opaque. Unlike Wikipedia, where I’ve just gone in and fixed things (usually broken links) myself.

Comment: I haven't heard from Mathworld, and there is no sign they will make a change.  I'm probably not going to pursue it.  If you're still interested in the question of diagonals concurrent at the limit point,  I've answered a similar question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386892/collinearity-in-bicentric-polygons/387006#387006 mainly by citing a 19th century text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In 2020 I gave a partial, somewhat hand waving answer to this question . It's further on under the heading **'Original Answer'***

---

### Updated Answer

##### Even-sided polygons

For the case of even sided bicentric polygons there are some proofs in the literature.

- [Lachlan, *Modern Pure Geometry*, 1893, pg 217, Ex. 4](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059156616/page/n233/mode/2up?view=theater).  This is given as an exercise at the end of a chapter on coaxal circles that culminates in Poncelet's General Theorem.
- [Halbeisen and Norbert, *A Simple Proof of Poncelet’s Theorem (on the occasion of its bicentennial)*, 2014, Theorems 4.1,4.2](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/poncelet.pdf). In my opinion it's not as simple as the title suggests.

##### Odd-sided polygons

The claim that *the lines connecting the vertices to the opposite points of tangency are concurrent at the limiting point* is incorrect.  For triangles the lines are concurrent at the [Gergonne point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GergonnePoint.html), which is distinct (albeit close to) the limiting point of the incircle and circumcircle.  For pentagons, the lines are generally not concurrent.

---

### Original Answer

The 4 vertex case isn't too difficult, and it suggests ways to attack the general case.

[image: Bicentric quadrilateral]

In the above diagram, $ABCD$ is a bicentric quadrilateral.  Points $K,L,M,N$ are the touch points with the incircle.  The diagonals of $ABCD$ and $KLMN$ meet at $X$. (see [Yiu, *Euclidean Geometry Notes*, pg 157](http://math.fau.edu/Yiu/EuclideanGeometryNotes.pdf)).

We want to show that $X$ is a limit point of the two circles.

[image: Polar of X]

To do this we construct the polars of $X$ for the two circles. (see [Weisstein, *Polar*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polar.html) )  Build the complete quadrilateral $ABCDEF$.  Regarding the sides of $ABCD$ as tangents to the incircle, we get the construction of the polar $EF$ of $X$ with respect to the incircle.  Regarding $A,B,C,D$ as the points where two lines through $X$ cut the circumcircle, we get the polar $EF$ of $X$ with respect to the circumcircle.  Evidently the two polars are the same, which implies that both circles invert $X$ to the same point $X'$ (which lies on the polar). So $X$ is a limit point of the two circles.

Assume $n$ is even. For the case of the general $n$-sided bicentric polygon, if we assume that all principle diagonals are concentric at a point $X$, we can use a similar argument to show that $X$ is a limit point.  This of course is just a partial result, because it remains to prove that the diagonals are concurrent.

Some further empirical observations and speculations. The setup for the quadrilateral case suggests a construction for bicentric-adjacent polygons (they are tangential, but not necessarily cyclic) that may be a useful avenue to a proof.  Start with a circle $C$ (the incircle) and a line $p$(the polar).  For even $n$ place $\frac{n}{2}$ points $P_i$ on $p$ and draw the $n$ tangents from these points to $C$. Then the intersections of adjacent tangents form a tangential polygon $P$ with the property that the principal diagonals are concurrent.  But $P$ will generally not be cyclic.  For example, when $n=4$ the polygon $P$ will be cyclic only if $\angle{P_1IP_2}$, where $I$ is the center of $C$, is a right angle.  For general $n$ it remains to show that certain configurations of $P_i$ result in cyclic $P$, and that for a given combination of incircle and circumcircle if one bicentric polygon has concurrent diagonals they all do.

I've ignored the case $n$ odd.  With any luck it follows from $n$ even.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and for the reference! My first impression that the proof from the reference is not quite simple. Besides the case of odd-sided polygons seems to be not considered.

Comment: @user, my impression as well.  And it doesn't get you any closer to your goal of a mapping from the regular polygon.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I would appreciate any hint how to prove or disprove the mapping conjecture.

Comment: Exactly what is your mapping conjecture?  If it's "[there exists] a mapping from a regular polygon onto arbitrary bicentric polygon with the same number of sides" I would say it is obviously true.

Comment: You are right. A real conjecture of the mapping does not exist. It would therefore suffice to prove or disprove that if three (semi-)diagonals are (non-)concurrent in the case of regular  polygon their "images" in an equal-sized bicentric polygon are also (non-)concurrent.